# SNMP Inventory find devices models

Tags: snmp

I want write SNMP inventory program. I know how to retrieve MIB strings, but I don't know how to find the device model. I want to be able to find the model of devices such as Cisco 2920 switches.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From SNMP standard, you can find limited information on device model detection, as it gives the vendors enough freedom.

There are two commonly used objects `.iso.org.dod.internet.mgmt.mib-2.system.sysObjectID` and `.iso.org.dod.internet.mgmt.mib-2.system.sysDescr` whose values should be used to query an existing model database you build on your own (or from the vendor channels).

Answer (score 1):

On Cisco devices, the model type can be generally by found by polling the `system.sysDescr.0` OID. This can be obtained by running the following command:

`snmpwalk -v 2c -c <InsertCommunityStringHere> <DeviceIPAddress> system.sysDescr.0`

The specific OID, here would be either `.iso.org.dod.internet.mgmt.mib-2.system.sysDescr` or `1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1` and then parsing out the desired field as you see fit (Perl, bash, etc.)

If you have other vendor devices to poll, I would recommend starting out by manually running  an `snmpwalk -v 2c -c <InsertCommunityStringHere> <DeviceIPAddress> system` to get a general idea of how the various devices respond and help you identify the proper fields you are interested in using for your application. Below is a sample output  from a Cisco 2900 switch.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You might also checkout the entity mib which usually contains a lot of information regarding
a SNMP device's chassis and other components. Cisco seems to populate this MIB quite well...

http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?local=en&translate=Translate&objectInput=1.3.6.1.2.1.47.1.1.1.1#oidContent

Parsing the model information from the sysDescr should also be possible for the Cisco devices. However, you have to deal with different formats for all the different hardware platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Both are working:

```
$ snmpwalk -v 2c -c ssss 195.149.160.226 system.sysDescr.0
SNMPv2-MIB::sysDescr.0 = STRING: Cisco IOS Software, C2900 Software (C2900-UNIVERSALK9-M), Version 15.2(4)M3, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc2)
Technical Support: http://www.cisco.com/techsupport
Copyright (c) 1986-2013 by Cisco Systems, Inc.
Compiled Tue 26-Feb-13 03:42 by prod_rel_team

$ snmpwalk -v 2c -c ssss 195.149.160.226 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1
 SNMPv2-MIB::sysDescr.0 = STRING: Cisco IOS Software, C2900 Software (C2900-UNIVERSALK9-M), Version 15.2(4)M3, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc2)
Technical Support: http://www.cisco.com/techsupport
Copyright (c) 1986-2013 by Cisco Systems, Inc.
```

**The thing is that you need to permit requests coming from the polling station in the device config.**

Еxample:

```
snmp-server community sssss RO 10

CPE-TIBC0-IPAC-58844#sh ip access-lists 10
Standard IP access list 10
    10 permit 199.99.99.9
    20 permit 199.99.99.8
```

Answer (score 0):

her is the OID you want: `entPhysicalModelName` .1.3.6.1.2.1.47.1.1.1.1.13.1

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest starting with a simple MIB you can find on the Internet and then re-write it using data types from your inventory program. There are also some good books like "SNMP MIB Handbook" and "Understanding SNMP MIBs" that are great resources.